# Disallowing users to view others posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I have a page that shows posts that another user makes, and I was able to make it so that if you go to the index, it only shows posts who's user_id is = to the current users user_id. But if i go to the url and change the post number, I can see other users posts and even edit them. I have tried changing the controllers show `@time_sheets = TimeSheet.where(:user_id => current_user.id)find(params[:id])` and have also tried using `<% if @time_sheet.user_id == @currentuser.id %>` in the view, but neither seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [RailsCasts Episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/385-authorization-from-scratch-part-1) check this and second episode, probably best method of authorization. Be aware that answer you approved just shows to current_user his posts on certian link, but doesn't prevent him from accessing other posts.

Comment: How would the person access it, I tried querying them through the url and now it 404's if you try to query posts that arent yours.

Comment: http://localhost:3000/timesheets/:id/edit (:id should be real) try it (correct port or resource name if it is not like yours)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In controller, you should have:

```
@time_sheet = TimeSheet.where(user_id: current_user.id).find(params[:id])
```

or, if you have association user has_many timesheets:

```
@time_sheet = current_user.time_sheets.find(params[:id])
```

It should work.

BTW you should of course check if anyone is logged in before calling this piece of code.

Comment: That worked great, also do you know how could i go about showing display an error page when they try to query one that is not theirs?

Comment: 404 will be displayed by default, if I remember correctly. Is this bad?
If it "worked great", would you mind to accept the answer? :)

Comment: Oh, im new to rails and I am running it locally so it redirects me to a page that shows the method that isn't returning. When you go to production I assume instead of these pages it will just 404 right?

Comment: What message do you get on development? `RecordNotFound`?

Comment: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /time_sheets/5
Couldn't find TimeSheet with id=5 [WHERE "time_sheets"."user_id" = 2] `then a window with the show method highlighting the line `@time_sheet = current_user.time_sheets.find(params[:id])`

Comment: So yes, it's 404 and you will get default 404 page (without backtrace) in production environment.

Comment: @Anonmattymous if you want render 404 page in development, you can use rescue for handle `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7244373/1297435)

Comment: You can also disable `consider_all_request_local` in envoronment and call your app with your real IP, instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't disallow anything, that just shows user his own posts, but he can still access everything by manually typing links with id

Answer (score 2):

You can use before_filter and redirect user to home page with error message if they are trying to access a page of a different user.

```
before_filter :validate_user

def validate_user
  timesheet_user_id = Timesheet.find(params[:id]).user_id
  redirect_to :root, :alert => "Unauthorized" unless timesheet_user_id == current_user.id
end
```

You can read more about filters [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)

Comment: `params[:id]` is time_sheet id, not user id.